# Wrong files include in c++

Tags: c++, include

I have some problems with including files in c++.

**record.hpp**

```
#ifndef record_hpp
#define record_hpp

#include <stdio.h>

class record {
......
};

#endif /* record_hpp */
```

**node.hpp**

```
#ifndef node_hpp
#define node_hpp

#include <stdio.h>

#include <string.h>
#include "record.hpp"


class recordNode: public record {
...... };
#endif /* node_hpp */
```

**List.hpp**

```
#ifndef List_hpp
#define List_hpp


#include <stdio.h>
#include "node.hpp"

class List
{.........};

#endif /* List_hpp */
```

**node2.hpp**

```
#ifndef node_hpp
#define node_hpp

#include "List.hpp"
#include "node.hpp"
#include <stdio.h>

#define N 5


class node {
private:

    List **key;
public:
    recordNode *k;
};
```

And in last file I have a lot of problems. Compiler does not know what it is `List` structure and `recordNode`. And I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: Both `node.hpp` and `node2.hpp` use `#ifndef node_hpp`, which is going to confuse things, and you haven't got a `#endif` in `node2.hpp`. Furthermore, please copy and paste the exact compiler error you are getting.

Comment: I just forget to write _italic_ **bold** `#endif`. I compiler with this. The xCode says `unknown type List`  `unknown type node2`

Answer (score 2):

In your **node.hpp** you have the following defined at the top:

```
#ifndef node_hpp
#define node_hpp
```

in your **node2.hpp** you also have the following defined at the top:

```
#ifndef node_hpp
#define node_hpp
```

I'd suggest changing **node2.hpp** to

```
#ifndef node2_hpp
#define node2_hpp
```

or something similar, and adding

```
#endif /* node2_hpp */
```

to the end of the file.

Answer (score 2):

This stuff

```
#ifndef record_hpp
#define record_hpp


#endif /* record_hpp */
```

is called an [Include Guard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard). It prevents an included file from being included repeatedly and potentially unleashing recursive hell and duplicate definitions on your poor unsuspecting program.

Consider something like `string` which is included by pretty much everything. Without the guard you could have `std::string` being defined hundreds of times. At the very least this slows down compilation. At worst really weird stuff happens and you spend hours or days debugging.

The logic goes like this:

If we haven't seen record_hpp (`#ifndef record_hpp`), mark it as seen (`#define record_hpp`) and copy everything in the file into the including file up to the end of the guard (`#endif /* record_hpp */`)

In node.hpp the guard is called `node_hpp`. The same name is used in node2.hpp, so

```
#ifndef node_hpp
#define node_hpp

#include "List.hpp"
#include "node.hpp"
#include <stdio.h>

#define N 5


class node {
private:

    List **key;
public:
    recordNode *k;
};
```

will expand to

```
#ifndef node_hpp
#define node_hpp

#include "List.hpp"
#ifndef node_hpp
#define node_hpp

#include <stdio.h>

#include <string.h>
#include "record.hpp"


class recordNode: public record {
...... };
#endif /* node_hpp */
#include <stdio.h>

#define N 5


class node {
private:

    List **key;
public:
    recordNode *k;
};
```

which, because we've already seen `node_hpp`, the second block guarded by `node_hpp` will be ignored and node2.hpp will become

```
#ifndef node_hpp
#define node_hpp

#include "List.hpp"
#ifndef node_hpp
#endif /* node_hpp */
#include <stdio.h>

#define N 5


class node {
private:

    List **key;
public:
    recordNode *k;
};
```

As a result, `recordNode` is never defined. Ooops.

The takeaway is never repeat include guards.

Also note that there is no `#endif` at the end of node2.hpp to close the include guard. That will cause some ugliness later as well.

Solution:

```
#ifndef node2_hpp
#define node2_hpp

#include "List.hpp"
#include "node.hpp"
#include <stdio.h>

#define N 5


class node {
private:

    List **key;
public:
    recordNode *k;
};
#endif /* node2_hpp */
```

More complicated projects will require more complicated include guard names because it is very possible that you could have two "list.hpp"s, one in your code and another in a third party library.